# Parts of my 3D character model keep vanishing

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, object-mode, retopology

As i am editing and shaping around and cleaning up the object, vital parts like the entire legs at first, and now the chest as well, they are fully gone in sculpt mode, and edit mode. Why does this happens?

Why i can't even do retopology on top of this?

Should i be more careful with these options i use frequently? Or is it a totally different problem?

[image: Delete loose]

[image: Merge by distance short]

This following picture is the very first body model i ever made. Here is exactly how my problem looks like.
Both chest, thighs and legs are fully gone, i don't know when.

[image]
again, with more precision
[image]

### Conclusion

To be fully honest, i don't have any idea how these parts vanished, **They only exist in object mode** and i have not deleted any faces or vertices of them, or any layer. i did join some of them but they were still edit-able... i don't know, they just magically vanish, i won't even be able to finish the legs more precisely.

Can you tell me

1. What is the problem
2. What i should avoid doing
3. is it possible to restore the lost parts maybe with retopology?
   )(any other advice is welcome)

### Final Edit

@3fingeredfrog huh, i did press Alt H like you suggested, on object mode, nothing happened, but when in edit mode i just pressed it and everything reappeared!!! thank you so much it worked like a charm, i never would know that would work, thank you so much!
[[image: its fixed5]

Comment: Perhaps while in Edit mode with the "missing" parts selected you hit the H key? The H key hides selected parts in Edit mode but they will not be hidden when in Object mode. The shortcut keys to UnHide are Alt H. To test this if this is the case,  in Edit mode use the unHide shortcut keys (Alt H) and see if the missing parts reappear.

Comment: +1 to 3fingeredfrog ... @Holdentoledo to attract more people avoid long story telling, go straight to the point, so we can help others too. Thank you

Comment: @vklidu I kinda tried, I'm very new to this so I didn't know exactly the precise thing to ask